# Anchors / Intra-links not supported in markdown

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I'm working on the OpenGL wiki page, and it would have been really handy if markdown supported intra-links. Wiki pages and FAQ pages can become really long, so adding a "back to top" link would be really helpful for navigation.

Example:

```
<h1 id="faq">FAQ</h1>
.. A lot of questions and answers ..
<a href="#faq">Back to the top</a>
```

If this is a case of PEBKAC however, please tell me how this can be done in markup, or the HTML subset it supports.

EDIT: "Back to top" is obviously just an example. It would be handy to refer back to sub-sections, as Roger Pate explained.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to have "back to top" links, as the user can just use the scrollbar, ctrl+home, mouse gestures, page-up, mouse-wheel, or whatever other interface convention they're used to.

This could be a useful feature to link directly to specific sections.

You can currently make links that point to anchors, but you can't insert the IDs with Markdown, at least not as it is supported by the SE engine.